# Create switch parameter using DynamicParam

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to create a `[switch]`-like parameter using `DynamicParam`? I know that I can just create a Boolean parameter, but in this case I will be forced to initialize its value like `-BooParam $true`, but I want to just type `-BooParam`. Why I need it - I would like to expose one switch parameter using Tab only if second is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using DynamicParam:

```powershell
function Test-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$flag1

    )

    DynamicParam 
    {
         if ($flag1) 
         {
              $flag2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
              $flag2.Mandatory = $false
              $flag2.HelpMessage = "Only available if flag1 is set"

              $attributeCollection = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]              
              $attributeCollection.Add($flag2)

              $flag2param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('flag2', [switch], $attributeCollection)

              $paramDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
              $paramDictionary.Add('flag2', $flag2param)
              return $paramDictionary
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Parameter sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx) might be a better (simpler) way to achieve your goal.

```psh
function Do-Something {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='none')]
  Param(
    ...
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set1', Mandatory=$true)]$Foo,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set1')][Switch]$Bar
  )

  ...
}
```